# AEM/CQ5 Dialog multifield not saving input

Tags: java, xml, jsp, aem

I am building a component which allows the user to add a multi field. When the multifield is added to the dialog, the user is presented with two text boxes. When the user adds information to the text boxes, and clicks 'OK'. When the dialog closes, no information is stored/saved.

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

See the dialog code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        xtype="panel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <heading
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                allowBlank="true"
                disabled="false"
                fieldLabel="Heading (optional)"
                grow="false"
                hideLabel="false"
                name="./headingTitle"
                readOnly="false"
                selectOnFocus="false"
                validateOnBlur="true"
                xtype="textfield"/>
            <message
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                fieldLabel="Message (optional)"
                name="./message"
                validateOnBlur="true"
                xtype="textfield"/>
            <link-list
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                fieldLabel="Tabs titles and binding"
                border="{Boolean}false"
                name="./link-list"
                width="1000"
                xtype="multifield">
                <fieldConfig
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    path="/apps/group/components/nab-broker-tabs/dialog/items/items/link-list/fieldConfig/items.infinity.json"
                    xtype="cq.compositefield">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <linkText
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldLabel="Titles"
                                name="linkText"
                                width="180"
                                xtype="textfield"/>
                            <linkBinding
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldLabel="binding ID"
                                name="linkBinding"
                                width="180"
                                xtype="textfield"/>
                        </items>
                </fieldConfig>
            </link-list>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: are there any errors in browser console or aem logs?

Comment: @awadheshv thanks for the response. No mate, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Since multiple values are to be stored, you should be using a custom xtype to store multifield values.
refer: http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-xtype.html

Answer (score 0):

In case of complex multifield components, I would suggest you to use **Multi Field Panel** from [ACS AEM Commons](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/widgets.html).

It will do the job for you.